# Problems with the 'Ubuntu classic' interface after recent upgrade to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, gui

I'm experiencing problems with the 'Ubuntu classic' interface, after I recently updated my ubuntu to version 11.04.

First of all, a small glitch.
Just look at this screenshot of the dropdown menu that appears when I right click the clock applet (but also any other gnome applet).

[image: Screenshot]

Look at the gradients...

Second, there's a more severe issue that I'm not able to debug. Sometimes, on an occasional apparently random basis, I cannot logout using the commands provided by Gnome GUI. When I choose "logout", completely nothing happens. The same if I choose "restart" or "shutdown". Last time I had to shutdown opening a Terminal and using "sudo shutdown -h now".

Is there any way I can inspect this mysterious behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that way on my machines as well, I don't think the gradients were an oversight as much as they may be a sacrifice to get something in unity working right.

As for your second issue you may check that dbus is running and accepting signals by running 'pgrep dbus' and 'sudo pgrep dbus' in a terminal. Without dbus the gnome session commands will not function.

Comment: dbus is running but gnome session commands don't work, on a random basis. How can I get the error stream of these commands, how can I see what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you dmesg after you tried to shutdown and failed?